# Windows Batch: find a string in file with "[" in the string

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a function already working to remove all lines which doesn't contain a string in several files, it's working great to use with common strings:

```
@echo off
set "string_to_find=level.waypoints["
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /B *.gsc') do (
            set "tempfile=%temp%\%%a"
            if exist "%tempfile%" del "%tempfile%" >NUL
            findstr /C:"%string_to_find%" "%~dp0\%%a" >> "%tempfile%"
            if not errorlevel 1 (
                        del "%%a" >NUL
                        move /Y "%tempfile%" "%~dp0\%%a" >NUL
                        if exist "%tempfile%" del "%tempfile%" >NUL
                        echo File "%~dp0\%%a" processed successfully 
            ) else (
            echo Problem processing file "%~dp0\%%a"
            )
)
```

If I search for just "level.waypoints" (without the "[") works fine but few lines that I don't want to keep are not deleted. I need to search for "level.waypoints[" to really delete all the lines that I need to, but because the char "[" make everything goes wrong, messing up with the temp files, giving in the end the error "file not found"...

I think should have some char that I need to put before "[" like "[" to make it work, but I can't find it... tryed already many without luck. :/

So how can I search for the string "level.waypoints[" and works?

thanks

Comment: You'll want an escape character. See this:  https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Comment: haven'tr tried your script but `findstr /c:"level.waypoints[" *.txt` works properly in my place. anyway you'll have better luck with powershell

Comment: @jmoon thank you! with that page I found out why with  "^" wasn't working and need to use just "\" instead. working great now! cheers!

Answer (score 2):

On the link sent by @jmoon says:

> Special Cases
>   A small number of commands follow slightly different rules, FINDSTR, REG and RUNAS all use \ as an escape character instead of ^

Tryed and works! so the end string is "level.waypoints\["

cheers!